# ng-src showing multiple images with random generator - Ionic 1 / Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-v1

I'm using Ionic 1 / Cordova.  I'm trying to select a random image from an array to display on the page (so that it's different each time the user visits).  I got it to randomly select a URL from the array each time BUT it will flip through 3 or 4 images on the page before stopping.  I know it's intended digest behavior for ng-src, but how I can prevent it or stop it after the first cycle?

HTML:

```
<md-list-item flex layout="column" layout-align="center">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <img class="logo" ng-src="{{resultgif(url)}}"/>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
```

.js:

```
$scope.resultgif = function(url) {

   {
  var answers = [
"images/1500.gif",
"images/1500.gif",
"images/2000.gif",
"images/2500.gif",
"images/3000.gif",
"images/3500.gif",
"images/4000.gif",
"images/4500.gif"
]

var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];

};

  return randomAnswer;
  }
```

Comment: I got it working... I created a separate function to randomly pick the image first, Here's the updated JS code incase another person runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you are attempting to get everything to display only once per cycle. I'm not setup for angular but here is a mock function that will help you. For Angular you may have to include $window to access localStorage but otherwise this will work with vanilla js

```
    const answers = [
    "images/1500.gif",
    "images/1500.gif",
    "images/2000.gif",
    "images/2500.gif",
    "images/3000.gif",
    "images/3500.gif",
    "images/4000.gif",
    "images/4500.gif"
];


let randomImage = function (staticArray = [], storeName = "store") {
    let result = '';
    let _seen = localStorage.getItem(storeName);
    let _seenArr = JSON.parse(_seen);
    let allArr = [];
    staticArray.forEach(function (element, index) {
        allArr.push(index);
    });

    let rIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * staticArray.length);


    if (_seen === null) {
        localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify([rIdx]));
        result = staticArray[rIdx];
    } else {

        let _unseen = allArr.filter((el) => !_seen.includes(el));
        rIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * _unseen.length);
        result = staticArray[_unseen[rIdx]];
        _seenArr.push(_unseen[rIdx]);
        localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(_seenArr));
        result = staticArray[_unseen[rIdx]];

        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName)).length >= staticArray.length) {
            localStorage.removeItem(storeName);
        }


    }

    return result;
};


console.log(randomImage(answers));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating a separating function to pick the image first then called that variable.  It now loads 1 random image each time.  Here's the updated JS incase it helps someone else.

```
 var winningGif = null;

 $scope.resultgif = function() {

  var sendGif = winningGif;
  return sendGif;

  };

function getRandomGif()     {

  var answers = [
"images/1500.gif",
"images/1500.gif",
"images/2000.gif",
"images/2500.gif",
"images/3000.gif"

]

 var randomAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
 winningGif = answers[randomAnswer];

}
```